# In predicate logic, why does P(x) and P(f(x)) have no unifiers?

Tags: logic, predicate

In predicate logic, why does P(x) and P(f(x)) have no unifiers? One of my solutions is replacing x with f(x), but I'm not sure why I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see what happens if you replace `x` with `f(x)`:

- `P(x)` becomes `P(f(x))`
- `P(f(x))` becomes `P(f(f(x)))`

And the result isn't the same; so it's not a unifier.

In general when the difference term involves itself as in this case (i.e., `x` differing from `f(x)`) you cannot unify them since whatever you substitute for `x` would change both terms in an unequal way, assuming they are not equal to start with.

Another way to think about this the so called occurs-check. Since `x` occurs in `f(x)` you cannot unify these two terms. You can read about the occurs-check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occurs_check